# Make React Select horizontally scrollable on overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

How can I make a React Select (specifically multiselect) component be able to scroll horizontally when the box overflows? I've tried

```
<Select
    // some other props
    styles={{
      valueContainer: (base) => ({
        ...base,
        overflowX: 'scroll',
      }),
    }}
    isMulti
/>
```

but that does not work. I am using React and Tailwind CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will work, and it's also a bit hacky:

```js
styles={{
      valueContainer: (base) => ({
        ...base,
        overflowX: 'scroll',
        flexWrap: 'unset',
      }),
      multiValue: (base) => ({
        ...base,
        flex: '1 0 auto',
      })
    }}
```

Please note that this will introduce new problems with scrollbars - on windows I assume the scrollbars will be visible permanently and mess with the layout, while on a Mac, the scrollbars will only appear while scrolling but then hide most of the content of the select value container.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Tailwind CSS`  then you can simply add the `className='overflow-x-scroll'`  to enable horizontal scrolling.

```
<Select
    // some other props
    styles={{
      valueContainer: (base) => ({
        ...base,
        overflowX: 'scroll',
      }),
    }}
    isMulti
    className='overflow-x-scroll'
/>
```